# Gardening Self-Evaluation: Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Comment: I'm not touching anything I answered. It's just a best practice.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, everyone!

Comment: @kevinsky It's not wrong to rate your own posts, as long as you are honest.

Comment: @J.Musser The best way to avoid a conflict of interest is not to go there.  There's no lack of questions...

Comment: I've done the last one, would you think I have created a conflict of interest?

Answer (score 3):

[What herbaceous plants like acid soil, blueberries and white pine mulch?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4410/what-herbaceous-plants-like-acid-soil-blueberries-and-white-pine-mulch)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question with a fast answer that is complete and has a reputable source. Bravo!

Answer (score 3):

[Removing weeds from brick patio](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4344/removing-weeds-from-brick-patio)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question to a common problem but the answers could have provided more ways to control weeds in pavers. Could do with more work.

Answer (score 2):

[Building natural stone steps](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/building-natural-stone-steps)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[Please shed light on argument about weeding](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4364/please-shed-light-on-argument-about-weeding)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: There's a lot of good ideas in the answers but I'm not sure if the original poster felt they got the answer they wanted. Some people who ask questions really want a yes no answer and in the world of gardening there are few topics that have black and white answers.

Answer (score 1):

[What edible mushrooms can be grown in full sun?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4455/what-edible-mushrooms-can-be-grown-in-full-sun)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think the question was out of scope then and now but the answer seems informative and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Are blackberries hard to control?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4458/are-blackberries-hard-to-control)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[How to care for a large redwood?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4441/how-to-care-for-a-large-redwood)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[Are my autumn blaze maple trees dying?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4415/are-my-autumn-blaze-maple-trees-dying)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

[Orange mold-like substance seems to be killing my bedding plants](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4372/orange-mold-like-substance-seems-to-be-killing-my-bedding-plants)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

[Can I grow a pistachio tree from seed?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4396/can-i-plant-a-pistachio-seed)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.